# How to set JSONP calls in sencha touch to Synchronous?

Tags: sencha-touch, jsonp, extjs

I'm creating a mobile app using sencha touch & facing a problem in asynchronous call of the JSONP I use, and I think I can solve it using synchronous call just like Ajax in Extjs 4.x :
[Ajax synchronous in Extjs 4.x](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?10857-Synchronous-Ajax-Call&p=646433&viewfull=1#post646433)

Is it possible to set synchronous calls in JSONP?
or is there an override to achieve that?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this quite extensively a while back, and found that it is not possible. This is because of the script tag hack used in JsonP. The only reason to use JsonP is to get around the cross-domain issues. To get around this using regular Json and set this header on your website specifying the sites that are allowed to make calls to this site.
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example

Comment: Hi Stumpy7, thanks for your reply.Yes.., I use jsonp because of the cross domain issues. So, should I use a regular json to get synchronous request? Could you please give me an example to set the header and access controll allow origin? Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

categories = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'categories',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost/php/server.php?action=catall',
    reader: {
        type: 'json' 
    }
}
});

its the json data
[{"catname":"HEALTH","id":"1"},{"catname":"IMAGINE","id":"2"},{"catname":"ENTERTAINMENT ","id":"3"},{"catname":"KIDS","id":"4"},{"catname":"LOCAL","id":"5"},{"catname":"TRAVELLER ","id":"6"},{"catname":"INTERNET ","id":"7"}]